# Using boxcollider2d.bounds.size.x gives me the wrong size

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

well i'm trying to use boxcollider2d.bounds.size.x to "snap" together 2 platforms when instantiating by spawning the platform using

`spawnPosX = lastSpawnedPlatform.transform.position.x + UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.5f, 2) + width;`

`width = boxcollider2d.bounds.size.x`

but the size is to small and the platforms overlaps. if anyone has a solution i would be very happy to hear it, please @ me if that's the case

I've tried moving the width declaration around to no sucesss

full code:https://pastebin.com/7Rn1dEBh

Answer (score 0):

```
    GameObject boundsSizer = Instantiate(choosenPlatform, new Vector2(99, 99), transform.rotation);
    choosenPlatformWidth = boundsSizer.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.extents.x;
    DestroyImmediate(boundsSizer);
    //jävla skit lösning här men men
    float spawnPosX;
    if (canDoubleJump == true)
    {
        spawnPosX = lastSpawnedPlatform.transform.position.x + /*UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.5f, 2) +*/  lastSpawnedPlatformWidth + choosenPlatformWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        spawnPosX = lastSpawnedPlatform.transform.position.x + /*UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.5f, 1.25f) + */lastSpawnedPlatformWidth + choosenPlatformWidth;
    }
    return spawnPosX;
```

fixed problem by getting bounds.extent on both objects but to get this i had to instantiate the objject to use bounds.extent then use destroy imidiate
preattyy bad suloution but it works